# Remote SAM user Query

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts

I’m trying to query user info from a local SAM database on a remote windows box.
I’ve got the syntax for a local call worked out just fine, but for a remote call I just can’t seem to find the right syntax to connect to a remote system.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine;
$User = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ct, "sean");
$User;
```

The C# code for connecting remotely is here:

```
    PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine,"TAMERO", 
                                       "administrator","password");
```

I Just can’t seem to get the right syntax for PS.
Has anyone done this before?

Comment: have you tried `Get-LocalUser`? you can run that in an `Invoke-Command` call to run it on the remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the `PrincipalContext` constructor in PowerShell you'd use the special `new()` static method:

```
#...
$principalContext = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new($ct, "Computername", "Username", "Password")
$User = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, "targetSAMAccountName")
```